# Checking for duplicates in List<>

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I need to check and display any duplicates contained in a List<> collection.

```
//Check for duplicate items
foreach (string y in myListCollection)
{
    if (myListCollection.FindAll(x => x.Contains(y)).Count > 1)
    {
        foreach (string path in myListCollection.FindAll(x => x.Contains(y)))
        {
            listbox1.items.add(path);
        }
    }
}
```

But this returns the entire list. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` instead:

```
myListCollection.GroupBy(x => x)
         .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
         .Select(x => x.Key)
         .ToList();
```

First `group` all items by their value then get each key from the groups that contains more than one item.

You are searching with contains which it won't return exact duplicate items.For example if you have `hell` and  `hello` it will add `hello` to the `listBox` even if it isn't a duplicate.Instead you should check for equality:

```
foreach (string y in myListCollection)
{
   if (myListCollection.FindAll(x => x == y).Count > 1)
   {
        listbox1.Items.add(y);
   }
}
```

And I don't think you need that nested `foreach` loop.Anyway, the above code will add duplicate items but still it isn't entirely correct.If you have four `hell` it will add four `hell` to the `listBox`.To fix that you can use `Distinct`  or you can check whether the item is already added but you don't need to. just use `GroupBy` as I showed you above.Also you can use [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to add all items to the `listBox` like this:

```
myListCollection.GroupBy(x => x)
         .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
         .Select(x => x.Key)
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(x => listBox1.Items.Add(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `Linq` Soln.

Using an additional Dictionary is another way when space is not a constraint: Speed: `O(n)`

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Read in every line in the file.
        List<string> myListCollection = new List<string>();
        myListCollection.Add("hi");
        myListCollection.Add("aa");
        myListCollection.Add("hi");
        myListCollection.Add("hello");
        myListCollection.Add("hello");
        Dictionary<string,int> dtCollection  = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        List<string> myDups = new List<string>();

        foreach (string y in myListCollection)
        {
            if(dtCollection.ContainsKey(y))
            {
                            Console.WriteLine(y);

            }else{
                dtCollection.Add(y,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> list= new List<string>();

for (int i =0 ; i< list.Count(); i++)
{
   for(int k = 0 ; k< list.Count(); k++)
   {
     if(list[i] == list[k])
     {
        list.RemoveAt(k);
         or do something ....///
     }
   }
}
```